# Is there a way of extracting a type of a extended type?

Tags: typescript

I wonder if there's a way of extracting a type of an existing type(that already had an extended type to it)

Example:

```
type GameInfo = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  version: string
} & HttpRequestError;

type HttpRequestError = {
    timestamp?: string,
    status?: number,
    status_code?: number,
    error?: string,
    message?: string,
  };
```

Now GameInfo has the extended type HttpRequestError. I would like to undo that and only get GameInfo type.

Something like:

```
const GameInfoWithoutHttpType = GameInfo extract HttpRequestError;
```

Is this possible?

ThanKS!

Comment: If you want them to remain separate, but still have a type with their combined shapes, I would make a third type `type GameInfoWithRequestError = GameInfo & HttpRequestError`

Comment: Yes I thought about that as well. But I am still curious if there's a way of "undo" the type extend type.

Comment: Nick's answer below is what you are looking for then

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a combination of the `Omit` utitlity type with `keyof HttpRequestError`

```js
type GameInfo = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  version: string
} & HttpRequestError;

type HttpRequestError = {
    timestamp?: string,
    status?: number,
    status_code?: number,
    error?: string,
    message?: string,
};

type WithoutHttp = Omit<GameInfo, keyof HttpRequestError>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a version >= 3.5, you can achieve that using Omit :

```
type GameInfoWithoutHttpType = Omit<GameInfo, keyof HttpRequestError>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your types

```
type GameInfo = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  version: string
} & HttpRequestError;

type HttpRequestError = {
  timestamp?: string,
  status?: number,
  status_code?: number,
  error?: string,
  message?: string
};
```

Create a utility type that decomposes arbitrary intersection types

```
type RemoveIntersection<I, R> = I extends R & infer T ? T : I;
```

And then apply it to the types in question

```
type GameInfoWithoutHttpError = RemoveIntersection<GameInfo, HttpRequestError>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4ghgWwgSQHYDMD2UC8UDeAsAFBRQCWAJgFxSoCuCARhAE4A0JZqiEtAzsFblUAc06koANzb9ymVAKEjRJAL5QAZFAASwYGABKEAI70IggKKtWmVgG4SJUJF36jp81Zt3cBLlDA5EiCiGAA-ErCYhJkocD0-JF0jCwcAfGJAPoAxpiUEMkMzGyxUGy2rMmC0eIBIfxwooVRKhJqjsQkAPQAVL1cvVAAglD0QQA25KCB4NAA7gAW5DmLUHmolNPyPBMTIFAFeQhgmPwWUHCzrgAGyDdQg1D89KuBi3DA7BToUHcP5H472gImAsggOSCCigmF+N0MDzgm0uqEwwEWbGuEG+jQONwAKjdvk9puUpHAJvRPhdgNgCTd7DD0Wx5oDoLS-vcAHSPUi9brOOZQYwITAyNBg1jnSE7AA8yG+hgAfH5kOUAB5gzZAwxaCgYTH4qDhKBG2jIRlOYguaDwJBoLAAdWmi0w4z0BmslT8IrFKFQkulUNQsrt-qw3w9HjMFmAXrsSqtG0EMNoYYdmGd6LdwCj8dYfiIkiotAALAAmb7dbpQADyAGkAjwkLQAET42Otqs1hsBGRSnZtgCMXIADFzS12oNW643JJl+GXR6XpzX8+p7EA)